# How to get sum of items in break from a cut function - R question

Tags: r, sum, average

```
data <- c(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 11 , 18)
c1 <- cut(data, breaks =  seq(0, 20, 5) , labels=1:4)
```

I would like to calculate sum for items in data which are in the first break and the average of items in the second break.

Please help!

Comment: What did you try? Where are you getting stuck? It seems like you just want `sum(data[c1=="1"]); mean(data[c1=="2"])`

Comment: I am beginner in R. I tried sum(c1[1]) which gives me an error.. With your suggestion, I get this Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.

Comment: Is your `data` vector not actually named `data`?

Comment: Nevermind you solution worked.. Than you!

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to include an "answer." You should post it as a answer below. That way people can properly up vote and post alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do, in my opinion, is to use a `data.frame` approach with `dplyr`. Then you can get grouped summaries for each of your `cut` classes with `group_by()` and `summarise()`.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(d = c(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 11 , 18))

data %>% 
  mutate(cut = cut(d, breaks =  seq(0, 20, 5) , labels=1:4)) %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(d), mean = mean(d))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  cut     sum  mean
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1         6     2
2 2        24     8
3 3        11    11
4 4        18    18
```

Answer (score 1):

MrFlick's suggestion is what I was looking for.

```
sum(data[c1=="1"]); 
mean(data[c1=="2"]);
```